# Access Violation in DirectX9

Tags: c++, directx, access-violation

Easiest way to put this: My code is throwing an access violation error whenever I run it. I have concluded it is the fault of calling `this->d3ddev.(whatever)` inside of the function `System::renderFrame()`. This function starts on line 112. If anyone could help me out here, that'd be great.
(by the way, I've gotten this working, but I wanted to put this code into classes, and that's where I started having my troubles. Also, I was told before to make sure to initialize all pointers. They are initialized, through `d3d->createDevice()`)

system.h

```
#ifndef SYSTEM_H
#define SYSTEM_H

#include "stdinc.h"


class System {
  private:
    void initD3D (void);
    void cleanD3D (void);
    void setUpHWND (HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    LRESULT WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

    HWND window;
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
    LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    LPSTR lpCmdLine;
    int nCmdShow;
  public:
    System (void);
    System (HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);
    System (const System&);
    ~System (void);

    void renderFrame (void);
};

#endif
```

system.cpp

```
#include "system.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class: System
// Private
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

void System::initD3D (void) {
    this->d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    ZeroMemory(&(this->d3dpp), sizeof(d3dpp));
    this->d3dpp.Windowed = WINDOWED;
    this->d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    this->d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = this->window;
    this->d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    this->d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    this->d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    this->d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    this->d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

    this->d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
        this->window,
        D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
        &(this->d3dpp),
        &(this->d3ddev));

    this->d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
    this->d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);
    this->d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);
};

void System::cleanD3D (void) { 
    this->d3d->Release();
    this->d3ddev->Release();
};

void System::setUpHWND (
                        HINSTANCE hInstance,
                        LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                        int nCmdShow) {
    this->hInstance = hInstance;
    this->lpCmdLine = lpCmdLine;
    this->nCmdShow = nCmdShow;

    ZeroMemory(&(this->windowClass), sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    this->windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    this->windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    this->windowClass.lpfnWndProc = System::StaticWindowProc;
    this->windowClass.hInstance = this->hInstance;
    this->windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    this->windowClass.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&(this->windowClass));

    this->window = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "WindowClass", "The Direct3D Program", 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        NULL, NULL, this->hInstance, NULL);
};

LRESULT CALLBACK System::StaticWindowProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    System *SystemPtr = (System*)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

    if(SystemPtr)
    {
        return SystemPtr->WindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else
    {
       return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
};

LRESULT System::WindowProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class: System
// Public
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

System::System (void) {
};

System::System (
                HINSTANCE hInstance,
                LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                int nCmdShow) {
    this->setUpHWND(hInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);

    ShowWindow(this->window, this->nCmdShow);

    this->initD3D();
};

System::System (const System &) {
};

System::~System (void) {
    this->cleanD3D();
};

void System::renderFrame (void) {
    // Update the camera here

    // Update objects

    // Clear objects

    // FOR SOME REASON THERE IS AN ERROR HERE
    this->d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), 1.0f, 0);
    this->d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    this->d3ddev->BeginScene();

    // Draw objects

    // Finish up
    this->d3ddev->EndScene(); 

    this->d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "system.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow) {
    System MainSys;
    MainSys = System(hInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);

    // Enter the main loop
    MSG msg;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        MainSys.renderFrame();
    }

    // Clean up DirectX and the COM
    //delete MainSys;

    return msg.wParam;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to compile your code and changed the following lines:

```
System MainSys;
MainSys = System(hInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);
```

into

```
System MainSys(hInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);
```

and it worked.

I admit I don't know exactly why it fails, but there's a lot of stuff in your System class and you are constructing two instances of it (once in both lines) and then assign one to the other. This is not a good idea in any case and unnecessary. I guess it has somethinig to do with Direct3D reference counting and you are not honoring it when the class gets copied to MainSys in the second line.

**EDIT**

I just noticed that the destructor of MainSys gets called after the class is constructed with *System(hInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);* So the just obtained device is Released() again.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but he constructs two separate instances of it, and then assigns one to the other. Your answer sounds like the constructor on the *same* object is being called twice, which is incorrect. In any case, if this fixes the problem, it sounds like the Rule of Three is being violated.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been bugging me for days, and it was something this simple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything imeediately wrong here but its easy to miss something.
I suggest checking the HRESULTS from every d3d api call to make sure something didn't fail, and assing assert(pointer != NULL) all over to try to catch the problem. Or step through with a debugger and look at the variables to determine when it starts to fail.

Also, if you've not done so, turn on the d3d9 debug version and look at the log. It often tells you what you've missed.